# Matlab: calculate pixel size of a string in label

Tags: string, matlab, size

I'm creating a panel in which dynamic strings are shown. I want to resize automatically the panel in order to avoid to see truncated strings (that are not hard coded so I can't know dimensions in advance).

So, given a string, the font weight, name and size, is possible to calculate the bounding box dimension in pixels, so I an use these data to recalculate dimensions of my panel?

Comment: It depends in the font. If you are using a monospaced font, then this is just a multiplication (nletters*sizeletters), else unless you have a lookup table with each of the widths of the letters, I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Have you tried to use the `Extent` property?

Comment: It seems to work, thanks!